# GetItemUrl page name casing

Tags: sitecore-api

I am creating a page url from a Sitecore item using the following code:

```
var pageUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item);
```

The Sitecore item starts with a capital letter, e.g. `Page`.

At one machine `LinkManager.GetItemUrl` resolves to: `http://<domain>/Page` while on another machine (same item and code) resolves to: `http://<domain>/page`.

How is this possible? Is there a `LinkManager` configuration that I am overseeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On **linkManager** definition  you have a setting **lowercaseUrls**:

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="asNeeded" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
    </providers>
```

I guess you override that setting.

On GetItemUrl is used that setting. If LowercaseUrls is false the link is not modified:

```
public virtual string GetItemUrl(Item item, UrlOptions options)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(options, "options");
    LinkProvider.LinkBuilder linkBuilder = this.CreateLinkBuilder(options);
    string text = linkBuilder.GetItemUrl(item);
    if (options.LowercaseUrls)
    {
        text = text.ToLowerInvariant();
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: That solves it. In my case the preconfigured value was changed by the SXA installer: `<linkManager patch:source="Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Catalog.config" defaultProvider="commerce">`.